# Read mail and add to SharePoint

Tags: csom

How to read mail and add to SP using CSOM and Exchange Web Services?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, are you on premise or online? Is this an app/add-in or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using EWS = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ReadMailPOC
{
    public static class GlobalVar
    {
        public static bool errorFound = false;
        public static StreamWriter logfile;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try { CheckEmailFolderForContents(); }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                GlobalVar.errorFound = true;
                //Log("Error\t\t " + e.Message);
                SendMail(null, e.Message, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
            }
        }
        private static void CheckEmailFolderForContents()
        {
            ExchangeService ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1) { Credentials = new WebCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exchangeUsername"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exchangePassword"]) };

            ews.AutodiscoverUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exchangeUsername"] + "@travelers.com");
            //FindFoldersResults folderSearchResults = ews.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
            //FindFoldersResults folderSearchResults = ews.GetFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
            //ews.AutodiscoverUrl("QUALTRAIN@travelers.com");
            //FolderView view = new FolderView(int.MaxValue);
            //ExtendedPropertyDefinition isHiddenProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x10f4, MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
            //view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.DisplayName, isHiddenProp);
            //view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
            //FindFoldersResults folderSearchResults = ews.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);
            FindFoldersResults folderSearchResults = ews.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));

            EWS.Folder exchangeExchangeAPIArchivedFolder = folderSearchResults.Folders.ToList().Find(f => f.DisplayName.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootFolder"], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            //Set the number of items we can deal with at anyone time.
            ItemView itemView = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
            foreach (EWS.Folder folder in folderSearchResults.Folders)
            {
                if (folder.DisplayName.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootFolder"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    EWS.Folder boundFolder = EWS.Folder.Bind(ews, folder.Id);
                    SearchFilter unreadSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, "Qualtrics", ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase));
                    //Find the unread messages in the email folder.
                    FindItemsResults<Item> unreadMessages = boundFolder.FindItems(unreadSearchFilter, itemView);
                    if (unreadMessages.TotalCount == 0) { }//Log("Error\t\tNo Mail found in " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootFolder"] + " folder.");
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (EmailMessage message in unreadMessages)
                        {
                            message.Load();
                            PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.Subject, EmailMessageSchema.Body, EmailMessageSchema.From);
                            propSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
                            var email = EmailMessage.Bind(ews, message.Id, propSet);
                            message.Load(propSet);
                            String mailBody = message.Body;

                            UpdateListItem(message, ews);
                            if (!GlobalVar.errorFound)
                            {
                                foreach (EWS.Folder folder1 in folderSearchResults.Folders)
                                {
                                    if (folder1.DisplayName.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArchiveFolder"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        var fid = folder1.Id;
                                        message.IsRead = true;
                                        message.Move(fid);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                foreach (EWS.Folder folder2 in folderSearchResults.Folders)
                                {
                                    if (folder2.DisplayName.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorFolder"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        var fid = folder2.Id;
                                        message.IsRead = true;
                                        message.Move(fid);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private static void UpdateListItem(EmailMessage message, ExchangeService ews)
        {

            string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];
            string Body = message.Body;
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["listName"]);
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                String[] values = Body.Split(';');
                var RequestSource = "";
                bool RNFound, RoleFound, EOSFound, DSFound, TSFound, ACNFound, ANFound, ACEFound;
                bool APCFound, ASFound, APFound, YCEFound, YTEFound, SPFound, TZFound, NotesFound, TopicsFound;
                RNFound = RoleFound = EOSFound = DSFound = TSFound = ACNFound = ANFound = ACEFound = APCFound = ASFound = APFound = YCEFound = YTEFound = SPFound = TZFound = NotesFound = TopicsFound = false;
                try
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var eachvalue = values[i].Trim(new Char[] { '\r', '\n' });
                        String[] valueset = eachvalue.Split(':');

                        if (valueset[0] == "Request Source")
                        {
                            oListItem["RequestSource"] = valueset[1].Trim(); RequestSource = valueset[1].Trim();
                        }

                        if (valueset[0] == "Role" || valueset[0] == "Requester Title")
                        {
                            oListItem["Role"] = valueset[1].Trim(); RoleFound = true;
                            oListItem.Update();
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "On Site")
                        {
                            oListItem["Will_x0020_SE_x0020_be_x0020_pre"] = valueset[1].Trim(); EOSFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Date Selection")
                        {
                            string dateString = valueset[1].Trim();
                            if (dateString != "")
                            {
                                dateString = dateString.Replace('-', '/').Trim();
                                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
                                oListItem["Date_x0020_Selection"] = dt;
                                DSFound = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Time Selection")
                        {
                            if (valueset[1] != "")
                                oListItem["Time_x0020_Selection"] = valueset[1] + ":" + valueset[2] + ":" + valueset[3] + ":" + valueset[4] + ":" + valueset[5]; TSFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Scheduling Preference")
                        {
                            oListItem["Scheduling_x0020_Preference"] = valueset[1].Trim(); SPFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Time Zone")
                        {
                            oListItem["Time_x0020_Zone"] = valueset[1].Trim(); TZFound = true;
                        }

                        if (valueset[0] == "Training Topic")
                        {
                            String[] SelectedChoiceVaue = valueset[1].Trim().Split(',');
                            List<string> Topics = new List<string>();
                            for (var j = 0; j < SelectedChoiceVaue.Length; j++)
                            {
                                if (SelectedChoiceVaue[j].Trim() != "") Topics.Add(SelectedChoiceVaue[j].Trim());
                            }
                            oListItem["Training_x0020_Topic"] = Topics;
                            TopicsFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Requester Name")
                        {
                            if (valueset[1].Trim() != "")
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    User requireduser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(valueset[1].Trim());
                                    clientContext.Load(requireduser);
                                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                    oListItem["Submitted_x0020_By"] = requireduser;
                                    RNFound = true;
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    GlobalVar.errorFound = true;
                                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                                    SendMail(message, e.Message, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Agency Contact Name")
                        {
                            oListItem["send_x0020_webinar_x0020_link_x0"] = valueset[1].Trim(); ACNFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Agency Name")
                        {
                            oListItem["Agency_x0020_Name"] = valueset[1].Trim(); ANFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Agency Contact Email")
                        {
                            oListItem["send_x0020_webinar_x0020_link_x00"] = valueset[1].Trim(); ACEFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Agency Producer Code")
                        {
                            oListItem["Agency_x0020_Producer_x0020_Code"] = valueset[1].Trim(); APCFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Agency State")
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                List stateList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stateListName"]);
                                var stateQuery = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='StateName' /><Value Type='Text'>" + valueset[1].Trim() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields><QueryOptions /></View>" };
                                var stateItem = stateList.GetItems(stateQuery);
                                clientContext.Load(stateItem);
                                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                oListItem["Agency_x0020_State"] = stateItem[0].FieldValues["Title"];
                                ASFound = true;
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                GlobalVar.errorFound = true;
                                //Log("An error has occurred:" + e.Message);
                                SendMail(message, e.Message, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
                            }
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Agent Phone#")
                        {
                            oListItem["Agent_x0020_Phone_x0020__x0023_"] = valueset[1].Trim(); APFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Years of Commercial Experience")
                        {
                            oListItem["Years_x0020_of_x0020_CL_x0020_Ex"] = valueset[1].Trim(); YCEFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Years of travelers Experience")
                        {
                            oListItem["Years_x0020_of_x0020_Travelers_x"] = valueset[1].Trim(); YTEFound = true;
                            oListItem.Update();
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "Notes")
                        {
                            oListItem["Notes"] = valueset[1].Trim(); NotesFound = true;
                        }
                        if (valueset[0] == "File Attached")
                        {
                            oListItem["File_x0020_Attached"] = valueset[1].Trim();
                        }
                    }

                    oListItem["AutoCreated"] = "Yes";
                    oListItem.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    if (RequestSource == "Qualtrics_Employee")
                    {
                        if (ACNFound && ANFound && ACEFound && APCFound && ASFound && APFound && YCEFound && YTEFound && SPFound && TZFound && NotesFound && TopicsFound) { }
                        else
                        {
                            //Log("Error\t\t Item successfully added to training_requests list with Requset Source : Qualtrics_Employee");
                            SendMail(message, null, RNFound, RoleFound, EOSFound, DSFound, TSFound, ACNFound, ANFound, ACEFound, APCFound, ASFound, APFound, YCEFound, YTEFound, SPFound, TZFound, NotesFound, TopicsFound);
                        }
                    }
                    if (RequestSource == "Qualtrics_Agent")
                    {
                        if (DSFound && TSFound && ACNFound && ANFound && ACEFound && APCFound && ASFound && APFound && YCEFound && YTEFound && SPFound && TZFound && NotesFound && TopicsFound)
                        {
                            oListItem.Update();
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                            //Log("Success\t\t Item successfully added to training_requests list with Requset Source : Qualtrics_Agent");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Log("Error\t\t Item successfully added to training_requests list with Requset Source : Qualtrics_Agent");
                            SendMail(message, null, RNFound, RoleFound, EOSFound, DSFound, TSFound, ACNFound, ANFound, ACEFound, APCFound, ASFound, APFound, YCEFound, YTEFound, SPFound, TZFound, NotesFound, TopicsFound);

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    GlobalVar.errorFound = true;
                    //Log("An error has occurred:" + e.Message);
                    SendMail(message, e.Message, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
                }

            }


        }
        private static void SendMail(EmailMessage inMail, string ErrorMessage, bool RNFound, bool RoleFound, bool EOSFound, bool DSFound, bool TSFound, bool ACNFound, bool ANFound, bool ACEFound, bool APCFound, bool ASFound, bool APFound, bool YCEFound, bool YTEFound, bool SPFound, bool TZFound, bool NotesFound, bool TopicsFound)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the reply response message from the original email message.
                // Indicate whether the message is a reply or reply all type of reply.
                bool replyToAll = true;
                string html = "";
                string notFoundError = "";
                html += "<html><head><style>.salut{font-weight:bold;}</style></head><body><div style='color:#1f497d'>";
                html += "<span class='salut'>Hi,</span><br/><br/>";
                //html += "<span class='salut'>Hi " + inMail.From.ToString().Substring(inMail.From.ToString().IndexOf(',') + 1).Trim() + ",</span><br/><br/>";
                html += "An error ocurred while adding the below item to the training_requests list.<br/><br/>";
                //EmailMessage responseMessage = new EmailMessage(ews);
                ResponseMessage responseMessage = inMail.CreateReply(replyToAll);
                // Prepend the reply to the message body. 
                if (ErrorMessage != null) html += "<b>Error: </b> " + ErrorMessage + "<br/><br/>Please resolve the error and send mail again.<br/><br/>";
                else
                {
                    notFoundError += "<ul>";
                    if (inMail.Body.ToString().Contains("Requester Name"))
                    {
                        if (!RNFound) notFoundError += "<li>Requester Name</li>";
                        if (!RoleFound) notFoundError += "<li>Role</li>";
                        if (!EOSFound) notFoundError += "<li>On Site</li>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!DSFound) notFoundError += "<li>Date Selection</li>";
                        if (!TSFound) notFoundError += "<li>Time Selection</li>";
                    }

                    if (!ACNFound) notFoundError += "<li>Agency Contact Name</li>";
                    if (!ANFound) notFoundError += "<li>Agency Name</li>";
                    if (!ACEFound) notFoundError += "<li>Agency Contact Email</li>";
                    if (!APCFound) notFoundError += "<li>Agency Producer Code</li>";
                    if (!ASFound) notFoundError += "<li>Agency State</li>";
                    if (!APFound) notFoundError += "<li>Agency Phone#</li>";
                    if (!YCEFound) notFoundError += "<li>Years of Commercial Experience</li>";
                    if (!YTEFound) notFoundError += "<li>Years of travelers Experience</li>";
                    if (!SPFound) notFoundError += "<li>Scheduling Preference</li>";
                    if (!TZFound) notFoundError += "<li>Time Zone</li>";
                    if (!NotesFound) notFoundError += "<li>Notes</li>";
                    if (!TopicsFound) notFoundError += "<li>Training Topics</li>";
                    notFoundError += "</ul>";
                    html += "<b>Error: </b> The following fields are missing or have a spelling mistake:<br/>" + notFoundError + "<br/>";
                    html += "Please resolve the error and send mail again.<br/><br/>";
                }
                html += "Thanks,<br/><span class='salut'>Training Team</span></div></body></html>";
                String[] toList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["toreceps"].Split(';');
                for(int l=0;l<toList.Length;l++){
                    responseMessage.ToRecipients.Add(toList[l]);
                }

                responseMessage.BodyPrefix = html;
                responseMessage.Subject = "ERROR: " + inMail.Subject;
                //responseMessage.CcRecipients = "mrandalp@travelers.com";
                // Send the response message.
                // This method call results in a CreateItem call to EWS.
                responseMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        private static void Log(string logMessage)
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists("logfile.txt"))
                GlobalVar.logfile = new StreamWriter("logfile.txt");
            else
                GlobalVar.logfile = System.IO.File.AppendText("logfile.txt");
            // Write to the file:
            GlobalVar.logfile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "\t" + logMessage);
            // Close the stream:
            GlobalVar.logfile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```